# Updating Record Without Query in The Database using Entity frame work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity

I am Using EF in My DAL. When I update a Record I have to Query the database using LINQ. This is Done in Performance Cost.

The Question is How to Update Records With out Round trip over all Database and also if I Have an Entity Created from Scratch and is not Attached to any object context how to Update its Values in Existing Entity in the database Without Querying.
Any Help Will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you can ad the record to datacontext like what i did in my code

im going to just update  VisitAmp field in my table

NewBranchRequestTbl is my table 
nr is new record

```
var newBran= new NewBranchDataContext();
    newBran.NewBranchRequestTbl.AddObject(nr);
                        newBran.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(nr, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
    newBran.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(nr).SetModifiedProperty("VisitAmp");
```

So when we call                 newBran.SaveChanges();

it just updates VisitAmp in NewBranchRequestTbl